# How to include the build date and version number in Sandcastle builds

Tags: sandcastle

I'd like the date when the doc was built and a version number to be appended to the footer of all Sandcastle builds.

I use the SHFB gui to create the project file and then automate the build using TeamCity.  Is there a way to get the build date and the TeamCity build # into the output?

Update:

I tried entering the footer text like Jeff suggested, but it does not add that to any page that I've seen.

[image: Sandcastle footer]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the TeamCity build number, but I was able to get the build date by adding this nonsense to the "Additional footer content" field in the Help File properties:

```
Documentation built {@BuildDate:yyyy\-MM\-dd}.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add replacement tags for the build date and time, like Jeff indicated. See 
[Customizing the build process](http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/?topic=html/69d998a7-1af5-4bf5-889b-59cd00b64000.htm) for more options.

The documentation itself has no version, but you can display the Framework version, but that's probably not what you want.